# MAX3000A clock enables

Tags: verilog, programmable-logic

I am digging into the [RTL diagram](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/657160/is-it-possible-to-decrease-timing-for-this-circuit) created by the Quartus. I see no registers with ENA input being used. For example:

[image]

created by the following code

```
always@(posedge FCLK)
    if(r_packet_state_machine[1:0] == {2{1'b0}})
        r_video_data[14:0] <= r_color_data[14:0];
```

Why not using clock enable when condition is true, instead of clocking the register on any clock cycle with its own data (except only one state when state machine is 0)? The goal is to minimize artificially introduced logic giving internal signal delays and complexities. Mux does clearly add delay here on the data path from the left.

Or this mux is a placeholder within "product–term select matrix" which is always in there and must be filled with some dummy logic? What is the ENA purpose then and what its benefit is?

I can't find any material information on how to do it. Here's the related [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/490770/verilog-code-always-block-not-working-as-expected#comment1247751_490774), but obviously it does not work for me.

What do I do wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: The RTL presentation is a high level logic. It does not reflect the actual implementation. See the fitted design in the Technology Map Viewer. What you see as a multiplexer in RTL might not exist explicitly in the final fitted design.

Comment: Thank you! Tech Map viewer is even more confusing as I can't see the way making it providing any details on the macrocell internals :( How to find these details out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTL representation is a high level logic. It does not reflect the actual implementation. See the fitted design in the Technology Map Viewer. What you see as a multiplexer in RTL might not exist explicitly in the final fitted design.

Unfortunately the Resource Property Editor does not support the max3000 family, so you can't see the intimate details of the macrocell configuration.

But you still should see the actual size of this part of the design. I've dropped your sample code into the new project, and it did fit it into 15 macrocells, exactly one cell per output register. So there are no intermediate multiplexers that would double the size of this module. I don't see any loops from the macrocell output back into its inputs, so I'd assume it did make use of the clock enable internally.

And even if it did not use the clock enable (idk, because your design is not as simple as the part you've shown), it's still possible that routing macrocell's output into one of its inputs would achieve exactly the same result as with clock enable, because macrocell inputs are significantly wider than your average 4-LUT on fpga, so the function of the multiplexer would be implemented within the same macrocell and would not put anything in between.

See the pic, the `r_packet_state_machine` condition (highlighted in red) is fed into the macrocell along with the `r_color_data`, there's nothing in between the cell and the color data. So you can conclude the macrocell is actually using the clock enable, decoding the required condition inside the macrocell itself.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My conclusion is that we actually do not know and can't know how it is implemented within a macrocell.